# having trouble converting from resource to bitmap in an android test

Tags: android, android-testing, bitmapfactory

Iam attempting to convert a resource image to a bitmap to test it in an Instrumentation test in android. originally i had this as a regular test extending testcase. my issue is with this

```
 protected void setUp()
{
 testbmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getInstrumentation().
 getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}
```

then i test that the bitmap is not null but the test fails.

```
public void testnotnull()
{
 assertNotNull(testbmap);
}
```

so iam doing something wrong here i think it could b something to do with the first param in the decoderecource(), maybe iam not pointing to the correct resources? I also tried getApplicationContext.getResources() method but iam not too sure on this one.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Have same problem right now, how did you solve it?

Comment: hi Tomas. I honestly cant remember. i try to steer clear of android Instumentation test now. just use plain old junit test by not having any android references in my presenter and interactor (using mvp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem changing `#getContext()` which will return Context of instrumentation's package to `#getTargetContext()` which will return context of target application.

> Return a Context for the target application being instrumented.  Note 
>   that this is often different than the Context of the instrumentation 
>   code, since the instrumentation code often lives is a different
>   package    than that of the application it is running against. See 
>   getContext to retrieve a Context for the instrumentation code.

Kotlin method:

```
@Test
fun bitmapIsNotNull() {
    val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.raw.any_image)

    Assert.assertNotNull(bitmap)
}
```

Comment: cool. glad you found a solution. try looking into mvp and mvi seems to be getting more popular also.